# How to post the dynamically created text box values to next page in php?

Tags: php, jquery

I am a newbee in php,jquery and ajax. I have a code in jquery to add and remove the textboxes dynamically on button click. I want to post the values of dynamically created textbox values to next page and display those values in next page. Any help is much appreciated.Thanks in advance.

I have pasted the code below..

You can also check the link http://jsfiddle.net/NSePb/1/

```
    $(document).ready(function () {

            var counter = 1;

            $("#addButton").click(function () {

            if(counter>7){
                alert("Only 7 textboxes allow");
                return false;
                }   

        var newTextBoxDiv = $(document.createElement('div'))
     .attr("id", 'TextBoxDiv' + counter);

        newTextBoxDiv.after().html('<label>Product #'+ counter + ' : </label>' +
      '<input type="text" size="22" name="product' + counter + 
      '" id="product' + counter + '" value="">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;\n\
          <label>Quantity #'+ counter + ' : </label>' +
      '<input type="text" size="1" name="qty' + counter + 
      '" id="qty' + counter + '" value="">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;\n\
          <label>Rate #'+ counter + ' : </label>' +
      '<input type="text" size="2" name="rates' + counter + 
      '" id="rates' + counter + '" value="" >&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;\n\
          <label>Total #'+ counter + ' : </label>' +
      '<input type="text" size="3" name="total' + counter + 
      '" id="total' + counter + '" value="" > ');

        newTextBoxDiv.appendTo("#TextBoxesGroup");


        counter++;
        });

        $("#removeButton").click(function () {
        if(counter==0){
        alert("No more textbox to remove");
        return false;
        }   

        counter--;

        $("#TextBoxDiv" + counter).remove();

        });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are creating the text boxes dynamically, i assume your text box names to be dynamic which i can't see here. So, store the dynamic field names in an array as

```
$request = array(#field names#) // comma separated
$requestJson = json_encode($request);
```

Pass

```
$requestJson as an hidden field in the form and submit the form.
```

In the next page i.e. in the action page receive the hidden field and decode it

```
$requestArr = json_decode($_REQUEST['requestFields']);
```

Loop the array and receive the values as

```
for($i=0; $i < count($requestArr); $i++)
{
        $value = $requestArr[$i]; // get the field name
        $content = $_REQUEST[$value]; // get the input value
            $fetchedResult = array($content); // Store the text field value 

}

Now your $fetchedResult will have the values to your future usage.
```

UPDATED - AS PER THE LATEST QUESTION ON COMMENT

```
var queryArr = [];

newTextBoxDiv.appendTo("#TextBoxesGroup"); // after this line add 
queryArr.push(product' + counter + '); // alert OR print in console to check the array values as and when the button is clicked.

$("#TextBoxDiv" + counter).remove(); //after this add
var removeItem = product' + counter + ' // #removed id#;
y = jQuery.grep(queryArr, function(value) {
  return value != removeItem;
});

$('<input>').attr({
    type: 'hidden',
    id: 'foo',
    name: 'bar',
    value : queryArr
}).appendTo('form');
```

Comment: Thanks for the swift response. In the code the textbox names are generated dynamically, I mean each time a user press the add button the counter value gets incremented and the id and name gets updated with that value.                                           name="product' + counter +'" id="product' + counter +'" . I hope the  way I followed creates dynamic textbox names. Please suggest me if it is wrong.

Comment: You are correct, so when the user every time clicks the add button, you add the field in an array and pass to hidden field and keep on appending the name to array. When removed you remove the field from array...So, here every time a text box is visible your array will contain that name.

Comment: I mean you are telling to add the textbox names to an array. Can you please give me a example on how to add the field to an array. Thank you for your help.

Comment: var queryArr = []; and below newTextBoxDiv add queryArr.push(#your field name#); when user clicks remove get the id and remove the particular value in your array.

Comment: Hi sandy sorry for raising one more query, I am facing difficulty in passing the array to hidden field. My javascript knowledge is very little, I feel my syntax is wrong.I have a hidden input field in html as below ,                                                       <input type="hidden" id="arrayvalue[]" name="arrayvalue"> and in javascript I am assigning the value of the hidden field as             document.getElementById('arrayvalue[]').value = queryArr[] ;        Please suggest if there are any links related to this

Comment: You are using jquery right, so i have given in my previous comment on how to add the values to array, then you can pass that variable to a hidden field.

Comment: Ya I am using jquery. Is the following syntax correct to pass the value of array to hidden field $('input[name=countervalue]').val(queryArr[]); I am building the array as var queryArr = [];
            queryArr.push("product + counter"); I feel its incorrect.I am novice to jquery and php. so please provide an live example on how to pass the dynamically created textbox names to an array and pass the value of array to hidden field. Excuse me for asking in detail.

Comment: I have added the code as UPDATED, i can give overview you need to go deep into it mate.

Answer (score 0):

You need use the $_POST superglobal, and use the id of the HTML element.

Consider this:

```
<form action="foobar.php" method="post">
<input type="text" id="an_element" name="an_element" />
</form>
```

If you wanted to display this using PHP, you would go to the page where the action attribute is pointing (in our case, `foobar.php`), and use the $_POST superglobal.

So the PHP code would look like this:

```
<?php
echo $_POST['an_element'];
?>
```

So, using your `rates` textbox as an example, you might want to do this:

```
<?php
echo $_POST['rates'];
?>
```

**Please note** that if you set the `action` attribute to `get`, you will need to use `$_GET` instead of `$_POST`.

Also, just taking a look at your code, you are missing the `form` element in your HTML. Instead of using `$(document.createElement('div'))
     .attr("id", 'TextBoxDiv' + counter);`, you might want to use this:

```
$(document.createElement('form'))
.attr({
id: 'TextBoxDiv' + counter,
action: 'foobar.php',
method: 'post'
});
```